# Масшабирование svg карты

Tags: javascript, php, css

Есть карта .svg, как сделать возможность ее масштабирования колесиком мыши средствами js и css?

Comment: https://ru.js.cx/task/scale-with-mouse-wheel/solution/

Comment: менять вьюпорт, потому что scale будет блюрить карту

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал использовать d3. Чтобы сразу был и драг, и плавность и т.д.
https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoom